# Office 2010 documents via Windows 7 symlinks on network share very slow in comparison to network path access

Tags: windows, networking, symlink, microsoft-office

Client: Windows 7 Premium, Office 2010 Pro Plus, both fully patched.

Server: Samba 3.5.10 on CentOS6 (SELinux enabled), Shadow copies enabled. Link speed: 1MBps.

As Windows 7 doesn't like me to use a network folder as a "Library" without making it offline, I used the trick of symlinking' them (like mklink /d c:\share\documents \server\documents)

Everything works fine - I can open the documents via:
c:\share\documents (the symlink)
\server\documents (the network path)
and X:\ (after a net use X: \server\documents ....)

Now comes the interesting part:
When I open an Office 2010 document - most noticeably an older Word version (97, 2000) which is being opened with Word 2010, via the symlink or, respectively, the "Library", opening the document is practically impossible. It takes minutes to open a small document.
BUT, when I open the SAME document via the direct path or network letter, the speed is satisfactory.

Did anyone come across this? Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention whether or not the same behavior exists with other files and since you didn't I'm going to assume that it doesn't.

Is it possible that you are seeing an issue with [Office File Validation](http://windowsexplored.com/2012/08/15/the-case-of-the-slowly-opening-or-unresponsive-office-files/)? I suggest you use a combination of ProcMon, TCPView and Wireshark/TCPDump to try and get a view into what Office is doing when you try to open documents via your symlinked directory. Additionally, crank the logging level up on Samba to 10 and see what *it's* doing.