# mklink to network share or UNC path or Mapped Drive?

Tags: windows, network-share, path

Are there performance or permission or other considerations to think about when using a `mklink` path to a network share versus just a straight UNC path (or mapped drive for that matter).

For example, can these three ways of accessing a network resource be considered functionally equivalent and roughly interchangeable?

```
mklink /d c:\shares\warehouse \\server1\warehouse
xcopy /s c:\shares\warehouse d:\temp\warehouse_copy
```

.

```
xcopy /s \\server1\warehouse d:\temp\warehouse_copy
```

.

```
net use X: \\server1\warehouse
xcopy /s X:\ d:\temp\warehouse_copy
```

Server is Windows 2003, clients are Win7 Pro. Network is mostly gigabit, though there are few 100mbit laggards here and there. I used a cmd shell in the example because it's easiest to explain, in practice the resource would be accessed by a variety of other methods also (Windows Explorer, Office "open" dialogs, system backup services, etc.)

Comment: possibly related to the performance aspect, http://serverfault.com/questions/411110/office-2010-documents-via-windows-7-symlinks-on-network-share-very-slow-in-compa (though it's unclear from the answer if this is specific to symbolic links or a general MS-Office and network paths consideration)

Comment: some posts [here, in 22-Jul-2011](https://crashplan.zendesk.com/entries/24338-Ability-to-backup-network-shares-Network-Attached-Storage-) indicate a potential issue with symbolic network links: *"...linked folders are not watched in realtime, so the software doesn't see when files are changed or added. Only scanning them (verify selection) finds the changes in these folders."*. This could be a real problem with large file collections (but perhaps mapped drives and UNC are also susceptible, so it's all a wash?)

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/210824/creating-a-symbolic-link-to-mapped-network-drive-in-windows

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend NOT using symbolic links that have a remote target.  My rationale being that a symbolic link makes an entry in the NTFS Master File Table, and although not substantiated, I reckon this could cause issues when performing low-level NTFS MFT operations (such as an offline CHKDSK).

As for performance, I can't see that there would be any difference at all.  Both result in SMB traffic.  The symbolic link route has to go via a redirection (handled by NTFS.SYS), but the "latency" here will be many thousands times smaller than any subsequent network delays...

Comment: You reckon? Any actual evidence one way or another?

Comment: I've had to do this for sharing drives with a service. Net shares are (apparently) not visible/available to services, but since the symbolic link is an actual file system entry it works.

Comment: Been doing this for a couple years, in production, on multiple workstations and servers and not had a single issue.